# How to round up in C

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const double TAX = 0.13;
    double small = 17.96;

    double subTotal = small * 6;
    double taxes = subTotal * TAX;

    printf("j   SubTotal: %9.4lf Tax: %9.4lf \n", (double)subTotal, (double)taxes);

  return 0;
}
```

The required output is

```
SubTotal: 107.7600 Tax: 14.0100 should come out.
```

My output is:

```
SubTotal: 107.7600 Tax: 14.0088
```

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Would `14.01` instead of `14.0100` be acceptable? (It usually makes more sense, and that makes it easier to do in code.)

Comment: 14.0100 must be printed out

Comment: @kaylum: Where in that question and its answers do you think it answers the question here of how to round up?

Comment: why should it output `14.0100` if the product is exactly `14.0088` ??  Don't ask for 4 decimals if you want only two, just `printf` using `%9.2lf` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to not *ever* use floating point types for currency.

If you have a decimal type available, use it.

If you don't, write one.

Or, at a minimum, use long integers to store cents.

Comment: Seen at the gas station: Regular 495 ⁹⁄₁₀. I am afraid cents do not provide fine enough granularity. Other than that, sound advice.

Comment: The needed granularity varies across domains, true.

Comment: Re “The solution is to not ever use floating point types for currency”: Floating-point for currency should be used with Black-Scholes options evaluation and other financial modeling.

Comment: i'm afraid the problem here is not of floating point precision or how floating point works in computers.  The answer is _exactly_ `14.0088` and he has asked for four decimal figures.  Why should the computer change it into only two? Anyway, you don't speak at all, about the rounding of cents (that you should do in the above case, working with `long`s)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to round to two decimal places, multiply by one hundred add one half, truncate to an `int` and then divide by one hundred. Like,

```
double round(double v) {
    return ((int)(v * 100 + .5)) / 100.;
}
```

Then you can call that like

```
double taxes = round(subTotal * TAX);
```

And I get (with no other changes)

```
j   SubTotal:  107.7600 Tax:   14.0100
```

Comment: You could extend this to have `round` take an int indicating the number of places, and instead of hard-coding `100` use `10` raised to that exponent.

Comment: `(int)(v * 100 + .5)` can fail to round correctly when 1) `v *100` out of `int` range or not finite 2) `v *100` is not exact and product near xxx.5, 3) `v < 0`.  Unclear why use the `+ 0.5` and cast when the standard library provides at least 8 round functions as reasonable alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

C provides useful rounding functions `rint(), round(), nearby(), llround()` that well handle rounding corner cases.

To round to the nearest 100th, scale the value by /100.0, round and scale back.

```
#include <math.h>

double value = ...;
value *= 100.0;
value = round(value); // or rint(), nearby()
value /= 100.0;
```

At this point, `value` may not exactly be of the form `ddd.dd` but will be the closest `double` to that form.  Printing with `"%.4f"` will then print to the closest `0.0001`.

```
printf("%9.4lf\n", value);
```

---

Alternatively, take money and round to the smallest monetary unit - suppose OP wants to the nearest cent (0.01).

```
long long value_cents = llround(value * 100.0);

printf("%lld.%02d00", amount / 100, abs(amount % 100));
```

---

Answer (score 0):

It’s a weird requirement to display four decimal places while rounding to two, but you can satisfy it by displaying two decimal places and hard-coding the characters `00` after it:

```
printf("j   SubTotal: %9.2f00 Tax: %9.2f00 \n", subTotal, taxes);
```

Comment: Currency, inexact floating point, and hardcoded portions of results.  What could possibly go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use floating point numbers for currency because they are tricky and inexact in many cases.  Here is a working solution that gives you the exact output you want, but you should know it is strange to print more than two digits after the decimal point if those extra digits are always zero.

The `+ 99` in the code below is the trick you need to make the calculation always round up, instead of rounding down which is the normal behavior of unsigned integer division.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void print_money_with_strange_format(uint64_t amount)
{
  printf("%llu.%02llu00", amount / 100, amount % 100);
}

int main(void)
{
  uint64_t tax_rate = 13;
  uint64_t small = 1796;
  uint64_t subtotal = small * 6;
  uint64_t tax = (subtotal * tax_rate + 99) / 100;

  printf("SubTotal: ");
  print_money_with_strange_format(subtotal);
  printf(" Tax: ");
  print_money_with_strange_format(tax);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Using fixed-point for everything means keeping track of magnitudes manually, which can quickly become a pain.

Comment: Which is why you should use a fixed-place type.

Comment: Using the wrong print specifier risks undefined behavior.

Comment: in the case exposed, the numbers have not been tricky nor imprecise calculations.  The exact result is `14.0088` so, why the computer should print `14.0100` if he demanded four decimals in the output?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to round the output to two decimals, but still producing four on output, just use

```
    printf("%9.2f00", value);
```

and the value will be rounded to two decimals, and two zeros will be appended to it.  But, why the computer should round `88` to `100` in a calculation, when you have not commanded it to round numbers at some place?

To round a number when the first decimal is over `.5`, you can just *add* 0.5 and then truncate the result.   In case you want to do it at some position, just multiply the number by the required power of ten (in this case 100) and after the truncation, divide it again by that power(100), as proposed by other answers.